# How to check if the system supports "Monotonic Clock"?

Tags: c, linux, unix, posix

I need to handle timeout scenarios in code and want to use `clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC)` if the system supports Monotonic Clock.

```
#ifdef CLOCK_MONOTONIC
    clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, & spec);
#else
    clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME,  & spec);
#endif
```

I'm not sure if this is enough. That's to say, is it possible that the system defines `CLOCK_MONOTONIC` by it does not really support monotonic clock? Or what's the reliable way to check if monotonic clock is supported?

Comment: Not according to POSIX/SUS.

Comment: `if (clock_gettime (CLOCK_MONOTONIC, &time) == -1) perror ("clock_gettime");` ??

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Per the letter of POSIX, you may in fact need a runtime test even if the constant `CLOCK_MONOTONIC` is defined.  The official way to handle this is with the `_POSIX_MONOTONIC_CLOCK` "feature-test macro", but those macros have really complicated semantics: quoting http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/unistd.h.html ,

> If a symbolic constant is not defined or is defined with the value -1, the option is not supported for compilation. If it is defined with a value greater than zero, the option shall always be supported when the application is executed. If it is defined with the value zero, the option shall be supported for compilation and might or might not be supported at runtime.

Translating that three-way distinction into code would give you something like this:

```
#if !defined _POSIX_MONOTONIC_CLOCK || _POSIX_MONOTONIC_CLOCK < 0
    clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME, &spec);
#elif _POSIX_MONOTONIC_CLOCK > 0
    clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, &spec);
#else
    if (clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, &spec))
        clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME, &spec));
#endif
```

But it's simpler and more readable if you just always do the runtime test when CLOCK_MONOTONIC itself is defined:

```
#ifdef CLOCK_MONOTONIC
    if (clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, &spec))
#endif
        clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME, &spec);
```

This increases the size of your code by some trivial amount on current-generation OSes that do support `CLOCK_MONOTONIC`, but the readability benefits are worth it in my opinion.

There is also a pretty strong argument for using `CLOCK_MONOTONIC` unconditionally; you're more likely to find an OS that doesn't support `clock_gettime` at all (e.g. MacOS X still doesn't have it as far as I know)  than an OS that has `clock_gettime` but not `CLOCK_MONOTONIC`.

Comment: "Personally, though, I would just use CLOCK_MONOTONIC unconditionally unless and until someone complained.", something that don't implement it don't deserve our program ;)

Comment: see my answer to see the interesting result on macOS.

Answer (score 2):

POSIX only requires that `CLOCK_REALTIME` be present, other clocks are optional.

If the monotonic clock is available, the macro `_POSIX_MONOTONIC_CLOCK` will be defined in `unistd.h` (according to the **Availability** section of the [man page](https://linux.die.net/man/3/clock_gettime))

Comment: All of the `_POSIX_` macros have really complicated semantics.  Quoting http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/unistd.h.html : "If a symbolic constant is not defined or is defined with the value -1, the option is not supported for compilation. If it is defined with a value greater than zero, the option shall always be supported when the application is executed. If it is defined with the value zero, the option shall be supported for compilation and might or might not be supported at runtime."  So you have to do a three-way #if and you might still need a runtime test.

Answer (score 2):

As shown in @zwol's answer, things really get a bit complicated and interesing ——

See the following simple program (`foo.c`):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <time.h>

int
main()
{
    struct timespec spec;

    printf("_POSIX_MONOTONIC_CLOCK         = %d\n",
           (int)_POSIX_MONOTONIC_CLOCK);
    printf("sysconf(_SC_MONOTONIC_CLOCK)   = %ld\n",
           sysconf(_SC_MONOTONIC_CLOCK) );
    printf("clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC) = %d\n",
           clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, & spec) );

    return 0;
}
```

On Linux (Debian 9, x86_64):

```
$ uname -a
Linux debian9 4.9.0-6-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 4.9.88-1 (2018-04-29) x86_64 GNU/Linux
$ gcc foo.c && ./a.out
_POSIX_MONOTONIC_CLOCK         = 0
sysconf(_SC_MONOTONIC_CLOCK)   = 200809
clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC) = 0
```

On macOS (10.13, High Sierra):

```
$ uname -a
Darwin macbook.home 17.5.0 Darwin Kernel Version 17.5.0: Fri Apr 13 19:32:32 PDT 2018; root:xnu-4570.51.2~1/RELEASE_X86_64 x86_64
$ cc foo.c && ./a.out
_POSIX_MONOTONIC_CLOCK         = -1
sysconf(_SC_MONOTONIC_CLOCK)   = -1
clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC) = 0
```

On FreeBSD (11.1, x86_64):

```
$ uname -a
FreeBSD freebsd 11.1-RELEASE FreeBSD 11.1-RELEASE #0 r321309: Fri Jul 21 02:08:28 UTC 2017     root@releng2.nyi.freebsd.org:/usr/obj/usr/src/sys/GENERIC  amd64
$ cc foo.c && ./a.out 
_POSIX_MONOTONIC_CLOCK         = 200112
sysconf(_SC_MONOTONIC_CLOCK)   = 200112
clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC) = 0
```

The result on macOS really surprised me. `sysconf()` returns `-1` but `clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC)` succeeds! Not sure if this indicate macOS is not POSIX compliant. Anyway it proves **runtime checking with `sysconf()` is NOT reliable!**

---

Finally I'm going with this:

```
int
Clock_gettime(struct timespec * spec)
{
    static bool firstime = true;
    static clockid_t clock = CLOCK_REALTIME;

    if (firstime) {
        firstime = false;
#ifdef CLOCK_MONOTONIC
        if (clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, spec) == 0) {
            clock = CLOCK_MONOTONIC;
            return 0;
        }
#endif
    }

    return clock_gettime(clock, spec);
}
```

Comment: I'm pleasantly surprised to learn that OSX 10.13 does have clock_gettime and CLOCK_MONOTONIC.  The associated `_POSIX_` and `_SC_` tests saying it doesn't, that's a plain old bug.