# Which standard defines the value of "sysconf()" options like "_SC_MONOTONIC_CLOCK"?

Tags: c, linux, unix, posix

(This is a follow-up question for [how to check if monotonic clock is supported](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50245373/) )

I tried printing the value of `_SC_MONOTONIC_CLOCK` and got `149`. I tried Google [search](https://www.google.com/search?num=20&newwindow=1&q=site%3Aopengroup.org+_SC_MONOTONIC_CLOCK+%28149+OR+0x95%29) on [POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/) site and got no results.

(Update after the answer: `149` is on Debian. Just tried on macOS and FreeBSD and both are using value `74`.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[POSIX states](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/unistd.h.html) that the symbolic constants `_SC_*` are defined in the `unistd.h` header:

> The `unistd.h` header shall define the following symbolic constants for `sysconf()`: [...] `_SC_MONOTONIC_CLOCK`

However, it does not define what is the value of such symbolic constant -- it shouldn't be important for your application (and you should not depend on which the value is).

For instance, the GNU C Library lists all of them [in an `enum`](https://github.com/lattera/glibc/blob/master/bits/confname.h); while newlib defines [explicit values](https://github.com/eblot/newlib/blob/master/newlib/libc/include/sys/unistd.h). [OpenBSD](https://github.com/openbsd/src/blob/master/include/unistd.h) and [NetBSD](https://ftp.netbsd.org/pub/NetBSD/NetBSD-current/src/sys/sys/unistd.h) also use explicit, but different, values.

Comment: i think the value must be the same on different systems. otherwise a program compiled on system A may not work on system B (e.g. different linux versions or distributions).

Comment: and on OS may be ABI compatible with another OS (e.g. [FreeBSD compat with Linux](https://www.freebsd.org/doc/handbook/linuxemu.html) )

Comment: @pynexj: There's no obligation that the values are consistent between different implementations — POSIX could not impose that requirement, and does not do so.  If particular implementations choose to follow some other implementation, so be it.  If there's a compatibility module between two systems, then it has to deal with any necessary mappings.  POSIX describes source code compatibility; it says nothing about binary compatibility.

Comment: Symbolic constants must be macros. They may also be enums, but the standard library still needs to provide macros (typically, as in the glibc case, of the form `#define _SC_MONOTONIC_CLOCK _SC_MONOTONIC_CLOCK`)

Comment: @rici: Indeed, what I tried to emphasize is that the values were not explicit, rather, come from the enum.

Comment: ok. the fact that OpenBSD and NetBSD are using different values says it all. as to how different linux distros can run the same compiled programs, i think that's what LSB is trying to standardize.

Answer (score 1):

This is an extended comment to [Acorn's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50265934/1475978), too long to fit in a comment. The intent is to clarify how this relates to portability to pynexj and others who are puzzled about that.

The constant `_SC_MONOTONIC_CLOCK` is defined by the C library, and may differ by architecture if the C library supports multiple architectures.

On all Linux distributions on the same hardware architecture, the same, or a binary compatible, C library is used. (Binary compatible in this context means that all those C libraries define the same value for `_SC_MONOTONIC_CLOCK` on the same hardware architectures.)

This means that code compiled for some Linux architecture on some Linux distribution, will work in other Linux distributions on the same architecture, if other dependencies (like dynamic libraries installed/available) are fulfilled.

At the source level, code needs to be compiled separately for each architecture and operating system.  Linux distributions that use the same library names and locations, can run the same binaries (if the necessary dynamic libraries are installed), as their C libraries will either be the same, or binary compatible.

Some other OSes have compatibility layers, to expose a Linux binary compatible interface for running Linux binaries. These can run some/most/all Linux binaries, depending how comprehensive that compatibility layer is. This is very similar to how Wine can be used to run Windows binaries in Linux.

There are certain oddball C library implementations, and possibly some manufacturer-forked "distributions" using modified/patched code, that are not binary compatible.  I've only seen these on embedded devices (specifically those that lack an MMU, or memory management unit, and therefore do not support virtual memory), not on desktops, servers, or laptops, though.